# Java ClassNotFoundException with maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I am getting ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError exceptions when I attempt to run my application using a maven defined dependency.

I added my maven dependency for the jar in question to my pom.xml file with the following declaration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>upload</groupId>
    <artifactId>upload</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\upload.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This added the relevant JAR file to my Maven Dependencies folder in Eclipse. I can access the classes in code but I get the mentioned exceptions once I run the application.

The jar is referenced in my Java build path under Maven dependencies:

when i am running the project am getting following exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

Comment: i tried provided and compile also

Comment: Which class is missing?

Comment: This jar is in the correct path? ${basedir} is well defined? The class name you are using is correctly typed?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you set the scope to `system`. When you do that, Maven assumes that you are taking care yourself that the jar is on the classpath when you run it.

From the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> - **system** This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

If you have a jar file which is not available in for example the Maven Central repository and you don't want to use `system` scope, then install the jar in your local Maven repository; see [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html). After you've done that, you can use a normal dependency with `compile` scope.